# PHP: Unnable to connect to Oracle using pdo_oci as SYSDBA

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I trying to connect to Oracle using pdo_oci driver. And my user has SYSDBA provileges:

```
$oraHost = 'x.x.x.x';
$oraPort = 1521;
$oraUser = 'x';
$oraPassword = 'x';
$oraServiceName = 'x';

$db = "(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = $oraHost)(PORT = $oraPort))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = $oraServiceName)
    )
  )";

$conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=" . $db, $oraUser, $oraPassword);
```

and got an error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: OCISessionBegin:: ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER
```

How i can pass the SYSDBA role to pdo connection ?

Comment: [Possibly related](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=56723); but [does this help](https://community.oracle.com/thread/348629?start=0&tstart=0)?

Comment: Thanks, i knew about oci8.
So, pdo can not make privileged connection...

Comment: @AlexandrMityuk were you able to find solution for this?

Comment: @casper123 Yes, user cannot be a superuser